# Get Customer Details

Tags: magento-1, customer-account, order-details

I am following [this](http://www.justwebdevelopment.com/blog/magento-get-items-in-order/) article. I would like to fetch Customer details like first name, last name and email using `Mage::getModel('sales/order')`.

Can anyone say how can I do that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch the details from billing address if it is guest user order. If you want to check registered customer you can use customer ID to check.

Please check the below code:

```
$_order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($orderID);

$customerId = $_order->getData('customer_id');

$billingAddress = $_order->getBillingAddress();

$shipingAddress = $_order->getShippingAddress();        

if($customerId != null) {
   $email = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId)->getEmail();
} else {
   $email = $billingAddress->getEmail();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$salesOrderModel = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(100000651,'increment_id');
$customerModel = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($salesOrderModel->getCustomerId());
echo $customerModel->getFirstname();
echo $customerModel->getLastname();
echo $customerModel->getEmail();
```